# Regex for Java Date validation

Tags: java, regex

Am checking validation of date using regex how it works for date but not for Year ? .Please help me to solve this issue.

Output :

```
false
true
false
true
```

Expected Output :

```
false
false
false
false


public static void main(String args[])
 {   
    System.out.println(dateFormatValidate("ddMMyyyy","^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0?[1-9]|1[012])((19|20)\\d\\d)?", "08s21988"));
    System.out.println(dateFormatValidate("ddMMyyyy","^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0?[1-9]|1[012])((19|20)\\d\\d)?", "08021s88"));
    System.out.println(dateFormatValidate("ddMMyyyy","^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0?[1-9]|1[012])((19|20)\\d\\d)?", "s8021988"));
    System.out.println(dateFormatValidate("ddMMyyyy","^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0?[1-9]|1[012])((19|20)\\d\\d)?", "0802198s"));        
 }
 public static boolean dateFormatValidate(String format, String regex, String value) {
        try {
            if (value != null && !"".equals(value.trim()) && format != null && !"".equals(format.trim())) 
            {
                if ((regex != null && !"".equals(regex.trim()) && Pattern.matches(regex, value)) || regex != null || "".equals(regex)) 
                {
                    SimpleDateFormat dformat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
                    dformat.setLenient(false);
                    dformat.parse(value);
                    return true;
                } else
                    return false;
            } else
                return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {     
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: if i were you i wil `org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils#parseDate` and catch the exception

Comment: Why do you need the regular expressions at all? You are already setting `lenient=false`, so the SimpleDateFormat should catch all invalid formats.

Comment: You should not check whether `format` or `regex` is `null` or empty. They probably won’t be in practical use, since that would be a programming error. If you want to parse a date, you *must* provide a format.

Comment: Date/Time cannot be validated just with regex match

Comment: @Artur he's using his own string representation of a date.

Comment: @sunleo also I wouldn't recommend `return false;` in your catch statement, you should use `printStackTrace()` instead, as you will get **false** value in case of any exceptions, which might be confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sunleo I don't think so it has anything to do with your regex, as I have just tried your pattern on these four dates you provide and it doesn't capture any of them.

I would say the error is in this `if`:

```
if ((regex != null && !"".equals(regex.trim()) && Pattern.matches(regex, value)) || regex != null || "".equals(regex)) 
{
               // your code
}
```

---

In the cases you provided in your **main**:

`regex != null` - all cases **true**

`!"".equals(regex.trim())` - all cases **true**

`Pattern.matches(regex, value))` - all cases **false**

`regex != null` - all cases **true**

`"".equals(regex))` - all cases **false**

---

Which gives us following if:

if ( (**true** AND **true** AND **false**) OR **true** OR **false** )

which is the same as:

if ( **false** OR **true** OR **false** )

which gives in all cases:

---

**true**

So why you still managed to get two **false** outputs? Probably an exception was thrown here:

```
SimpleDateFormat dformat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
dformat.setLenient(false);
dformat.parse(value);
```

So in your `catch` statement change `return false` to `e.printStackTrace();`.

Also my recommendation would be to rearrange this particular **if** first then check it for the cases that should be false (in this example all of them).
How?

First rearrange **if** then I would start with debugging and checking the **if** components to see their values and if they are computed correctly.

Also I think the regex is not correct at all (even if it's not the cause of the wrong output), if you always use **ddMMyyyy** format and only 19xx/20xx years, try this pattern:

```
^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(19|20)\d{2}$
```

---

**NOTE**

I have not checked any of this (except regex) via any IDE as I do not have any here.